# Type def struct C objective to C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, typedef

I want to know how can i convert a "typedef struct" in objective C to a c++ code preferably make into a class. is it possible ? can i used classes ?

Example :

```
typedef struct{
    int one;
    int two;
}myStruct;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no fundamental difference between `struct` and `class` in C++<sup>*</sup>. This is a type `mystruct` with two public data members:

```
struct mystruct {
    int one;
    int two;
};
```

This is *exactly the same type* as

```
class mystruct
{
  public:
    int one;
    int two;
};
```

<sup>* The difference is that members and base classes are public by default in a `struct` and private in a `class`. The two keywords can be used to express the same types.</sup>

Comment: There is a difference between the default accessors

Comment: @ThePlatypus Right, no fundamental difference. The compiler will not know the difference between `class Foo { int i; };` and `struct Foo { private: int i; };` for example.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, missed the word.

Comment: Beat me to it with a better answer, have an upvote :). In case it isn't clear to OP or others, members of c++ `class` types are default PRIVATE, while `struct` members are default PUBLIC.

Comment: @juanchopanza +1, I misread the OP question. I thought we were talking converting this to C#, which would have made the fields private by default. I don't know why this was tagged with C#.

Comment: @BaylesJ thanks, you made me realise I had messed up the explanation in the footnote. That is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all that standard stuff about reading some good books on C++ applies.

In C++, structs ARE classes, the only difference is the default visibility of class members AND that no typedef is necessary for these objects, myStruct is automatically useable as if you typedef'd it. Thus you would have:

```
struct myStruct {
    int one;
    int two;
};
```

and you can add member functions and all that on top of this. Plain Old Data (POD) structs are also fine in C++.